# Magento Home Page Renders as Source HTML

Tags: php, apache, magento

I just migrated a Magento site and the homepage loads as plain text but a php info page and all the admin area is fine...anyone seen this before?

All modules and configs are setup correctly, I've migrated these heaps before so assume it's something out of left field.

Cheers,
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had that issue, I have solved by giving rights recursive to var and media folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var
sudo chmod -R 777 media
```

Comment: It wasn't that...I had that before too...for some reason it's delivering content as text/css mime type when I set it to use the custom theme...default theme is ok though

however I have this setup on another test server and my local ubuntu setup and it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so cue the most random solution

I used a extension which required IonCube so I needed to configure a couple of other things using the IonCube Loader Wizard...that was it.

No errors, no logs, no nothing